# Azure devops service connection expired and cannot edit/renew

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a Service Connection which is being used for Pipelines in Azure DevOps. It was created by another user some time ago. Recently it expired and would not allow me to change the username it was associated with. So I deleted that Service Connection and created a new one, and it took me a lot of time to modify each Pipeline where it was being used.

I have two questions.

1. Is it possible to change the creator name of the Service Connection?
2. If not, is there any other way to reuse an existing Service Connection after its secret expires?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of service conection? Azure Rm? I am asking because it may be vary.

Comment: @Krzysztof Madej , it is Azure Resource Manager

Comment: If you are receiving an error "GetUserAccessToken: Failed to obtain an access token of identity 28b1bb12-b4b6-75b0-89b4-c13eaa993e5e. AAD returned silent failure." when trying to update the service connection, open the browser in incognito mode, and try again. Hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 80):

I just got stuck in the same position trying to manually update the connection with a new client secret. Here's what worked for me:

- From the DevOps Service Connection | Click Manage Service Principal
- Then on the service principal | Certificates & Secrets
- Create a "New Client Secret"
- Delete the expired secret
- Return to the DevOps Service Connection
- Click Edit - click the verify button. It should tell you the client certificate has expired
- Now you need to make a meaningless change and save it. I just type a character in to the optional description and save.
- Now edit again and click verify, it will now pick up the new client secret and all is happy. Just go delete the meaningless character you typed into the description and click save.

Comment: While not very intuitive, this indeed works! No need to delete the expired secret though.

Comment: Cheers for the flow. The no-edit save for the Service Connection on AzDO side is also instructed in MS docs: [azure/devops/pipelines/release/azure-rm-endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/azure-rm-endpoint?view=azure-devops#service-principals-token-expired)

Comment: This just helped me i didnt understand why it couldnt verify, how did i put in my secret? turns out, you dont put in a secret. It does that when verifying, thank you this was very helpful!

Comment: This answer helped me a lot! Based on this answer I've prepared a small guide (with images) for anyone else struggling on how to fix this problem. https://piotr.gg/dev-ops/how-to-update-azure-devops-service-principal-connection-once-expired.html

Comment: Great answer - ty - one question: what's are the options for being notified before they expire??

Comment: It is extremely sad that this answer has helped so many people including me

Comment: Where do you see the button "Manage Service Principal"? I'm on that page and there is only "Edit" and "3 dots" pointing to "Approvals and checks" and "Security" and "Delete".

Comment: Saved my bacon today, thanks!

Comment: worked for me too and save me a ton of work - should be the accept answer?

Comment: It's worth noting... I had to do this today, and the "Verify" button as described in the answer doesn't seem to exist. Maybe it's changed, or maybe it's because I'm using a Secret rather than a Certificate. In any case, editing the description and saving still worked, so don't be scared off from this answer if it doesn't perfectly describe what you're seeing.

Comment: GEEEZ. Thank you. Very frustrating.

Comment: We also noticed that the account you're using to update the description in DevOps, needs to have Owner or User Access Administrator permissions in Azure.

Answer (score 2):

Defining service connection you can pick a name what you want. So in your case you can reuse old name to minimize your work.

[image]

If you ahve already define service connection you can change a name using [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/serviceendpoint/endpoints/update%20service%20endpoint?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1):

```
PUT https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/serviceendpoint/endpoints/{endpointId}?api-version=5.1-preview.2
```

You can also edit it from the poertal:
[image]

and then:

[image]

Comment: Please read my notes what I have posted before. Whenever the service connection got expired, is there any way to use the existed one with out deleting because it (the newly created service connection) is taking so much time to configure in the pipelines

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using automatic authentication method. Automatic configured service connection does't allow updating the connection name or other information. You could try manual authentication method or Managed identity.

[image]

Comment: the existed service connections all are manual and those were created by others. So is there any way to edit the existed one(created by others)

Comment: I've tested with Azure Resource Manager using managed identity, which can only modify the service connection name.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue that I couldn't edit an Azure RM Service Connection that had an expired client credential. However, turning off "New service connections experience" in the Preview features blade made it possible to update using the old service connection dialog.

Comment: in my organization they won't allow to change those settings, so is there any other options to change(some "X" employee left the project and then I want to update the service connection which was created by that "X" employee)