Unable to renew expired secrets for Azure DevOps service connections
I have some Azure DevOps service connections whose secrets have expired. I am unable to renew them using any approach. There are a few Stack overflow posts and answers, but none of them seem to work for me.
Type of Service connection: Azure Resource Manager using service principal (automatic)
These service connections are created by past employees, so I am not the creator and I believe there is no way to change it.
I have administrator access over these service connections in DevOps.
I have Global Administrator, User Access Administrator and Contributor privileges in Azure.
Based on this post - https://stackoverflow.com/a/69158265/3804477
I created a new service connection(automatic), accessed its App registration in Azure, deleted its secret, followed the steps in the above post and it works without any hiccups. The problem is only when I try to renew the existing connections created by past employees.
No luck with MS documentation either - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/azure-rm-endpoint?view=azure-devops#service-principals-token-expired
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

If you configure the Azure Resource Manager service connection (ARM service connection) as "Service principal (automatic)", when the secret is expired, you normally can refresh the secret by doing some update on the ARM service connection. for example, update the Service connection name or the Description, and then save the update. When saving, it will automatically try to refresh secret for the ARM service connection.

Now, Azure DevOps has provided the new ways that using Workload Identity federation to configure the ARM service connection, and it is the recommended method.

Workload Identity federation (automatic)
Workload Identity federation (manual)

If using Workload Identity federation, you do not need to have a secret for use, so you will no longer worry the credential will be expired at some time in the future. So, I recommend you switch your ARM service connections to use Workload Identity federation.

If you do not have an exist Service principal:
You can select Workload Identity federation (automatic) to quicky configure an ARM service connection using Workload Identity federation. You just need to provide the Subscription, Resource group (optional) and Service connection name.


If you have an exist Service principal:
You can select Workload Identity federation (manual) to manually an ARM service connection using Workload Identity federation.

Select "Workload Identity federation (manual)" > "Next". Give a customized name to the service connection to complete Step 1. Click "Next" to open Step 2.


Open the Service principal on Azure Portal. Then go to "Certificates & secrets" > "Federated credentials" tab to add a new credential.


Fill in the required information on the new credential.

Federated credential scenario: Other issuer
Issuer: Copy from Step 2 on the new service connection window.
Subject identifier: Copy from Step 2 on the new service connection window.
Name: A customized name of the new credential.



Back to the new service connection window to complete Step 2.



After completing above steps, in the pipelines, you can use this ARM service connection as normal.
For more details, you can reference the documentation "Connect to Azure by using an Azure Resource Manager service connection".


Thanks for your response.
Your first part of the response with editing name/description and saving - doesn't work for me as mentioned in my post.
I have heard about Workload Identity Federation but haven't really given it a got yet. If nothing works, then might try it.

@VipeenSekharan, No problem. If you still cannot refresh the secret on the previous ARM service connection, as a workaround, you can create a new service connection. Anyway, I still recommend you try to use Workload Identity federation to configure the service connection. You just need to follow the steps I shared above.

I am unable to use workload identity federation due to company policy. The only way I got this to work was to rotate the service connections themselves, rotating just the creds didn't work for me. It is quite a finicky process in DevOps:

Activate Entra admin roles (if necessary)
Navigate to Project Settings -> 'Service connections'
Delete the service connection concerned
Navigate to the broken pipeline
Select the subscription from the down and hit "Authorize". This will re-create the service connection with new credentials
In my case the pipelines also manage DB migrations and SQL Server will cache the creds, so I needed to re-add the external identity to the relevant DB (drop user / create form external provider / add role)


This is advice from what has worked several times for me, but with client secrets, i assume it might work for the other methods aswell.

Go to Certificates & Secrets for the app registration and generate your new secret
Delete the old one, so you only have one
Edit your azure devops service connection (a meaningless edit like description) to allow it to be saved.
Save the connection, and wait a few seconds.
Go back to the connection and test it with the verify button.
It should now have hooked up to the new secret and be working again.

